# Update Component once ref.current is changing

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My goal is to render the following code as soon `joinedRef.current` changes to true. From the React documentation I learned, that React doesn't inform when `.current` is changing, which now gives me the challenge, that my button is not rendered. In the documentation they refer [here.](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-can-i-measure-a-dom-node)

However, I am not sure how to change my code to make this work. My best idea is to add an `useState` effect on top instead. But how to solve with `useCallback` which seems to be the better approach?

Extract of Component

```
{joinedRef.current && (
  <>
    {console.log(joinedRef.current)}
    <Portal container={actionToolbarAnchor.current}>
      <ActionToolbarButton
        title="Video Call Settings"
        onClick={handlePortalClick}
      >
        <Icon icon={faCog} />
      </ActionToolbarButton>
    </Portal>
  </>
)}
```

Component

```
const IntegrationDaily = ({ eventSlug, elementId, participants }) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const iframeRef = useRef();
  const dailyRef = useRef();
  const joinedRef = useRef();
  const joiningRef = useRef();
  const actionToolbarAnchor = useActionToolbar();

  useEffect(() => {
    dailyRef.current = DailyIframe.wrap(iframeRef.current, {
      // showLeaveButton: true,
    });

    dailyRef.current.on(eventTypes.LEFT_MEETING, () => {
      joinedRef.current = false;
    });

    dailyRef.current.on(eventTypes.JOINING_MEETING, () => {
      joiningRef.current = true;
    });

    dailyRef.current.on(eventTypes.JOINED_MEETING, () => {
      joiningRef.current = false;
      joinedRef.current = true;
    });

    return () => {
      joinedRef.current && dailyRef.current.destroy();
    };
  }, []);

  const handlePortalClick = () => {
    console.log(dailyRef.current);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <iframe
        ref={iframeRef}
        className={classes.root}
        title="Video Meeting"
        frameBorder="0"
        allow="camera; microphone; display-capture; fullscreen"
      />
      {joinedRef.current && (
        <>
          {console.log(joinedRef.current)}
          <Portal container={actionToolbarAnchor.current}>
            <ActionToolbarButton
              title="Video Call Settings"
              onClick={handlePortalClick}
            >
              <Icon icon={faCog} />
            </ActionToolbarButton>
          </Portal>
        </>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default IntegrationDaily;
```

Comment: What is the problem of using `setState`? I am not sure how ref's are helpful in your case. Ref's are required when you to play with dom changes and you dont want to render your component. In your case it looks like data changing so why dont use state's?

Answer (score 0):

Irrelevant to the code you have given - following is an explanation regarding the link from the react-docs;

`useCallback` is used to avoid redefining the function with each render - since the dependency list is empty;

`measuredRef` is a `callback` type of ref-signature - which means that attribute `ref` in react-js also takes function with signature - `node => {//...do smthing with node}`;

Trying to use the same in the code above could result something like this -

```
//...
const [joiningRef, setJoiningRef] = useState(false);
const [joinedRef, setJoinedRef] = useState(false);
const dailyRef = useRef();

useEffect(()=>{
     return ()=>{
          joinedRef && dailyRef.current && dailyRef.current.destroy()
     }
  }, [])

const iframeRef = useCallback((frame) => {
    if(!frame){
        if(dailyRef.current){
            dailyRef.current = null;
        }
        return;
    }
    
    const dframe = DailyIframe.wrap(frame, {
      // showLeaveButton: true,
    });

    dframe.on(eventTypes.LEFT_MEETING, () => {
      setJoinedRef(false);
    });

    dframe.on(eventTypes.JOINING_MEETING, () => {
      setJoiningRef(true);
    });

    dframe.on(eventTypes.JOINED_MEETING, () => {
      setJoiningRef(false);
      setJoinedRef(true);
    });
    
    dailyRef.current = dframe;
  }, []);

 useEffect(()=>{
    // react when joinedRef changes;
 },[joinedRef])

// use `joinedRef` rather than `joinedRef.current` to conditionally show the Portal fragment
//...
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Just one thing I was confused about is where `frame` is coming from. Is that something I also have to define as `const frame = useRef()` above?

I have seen it is the same in the React doc example I posted. However, its also not clear to me where `node` is coming from here.

Comment: @JoeyCoder - that is a predefined structure with react, ie. in the react-library - this might be implemented like - if `ref` is a `function` passed in a component, then call that function with the apt html-dom;

When developing components - this feature is available for us to get that dom node and do something with it by passing a function to the ref;

And you don't have to define `const frame = useRef()`